# load_user function gets None as a parameter

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm building a very simple Flask application, when I implemented load_user from flask-login, I started having errors because the function was getting None passed to it and was trying to query using a None value.

```
from flask_login import LoginManager

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(id)
```

Possibly relevant files:

auth/__init__.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__, url_prefix='/auth')

from . import views
```

auth/views.py:

```
from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for, flash, session
from flask_login import login_user
from app.forms import LoginForm
from app.models import User
from app.queries import get_user
from . import auth

@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    login_form = LoginForm()
    context = {
        'login_form' : login_form
    }
    username = login_form.username.data
    password = login_form.password.data
    if login_form.validate_on_submit():
        user_query = get_user(username)
        if user_query:
            db_password = user_query.password

            if password == db_password:
                registeredUser = User(username = username,
                                      password = password)
                login_user(registeredUser)
                flash('Bienvenido de nuevo!', 'alert alert-success alert-dismissible')

                return redirect(url_for('hello'))

            else:
                flash('La información no coincide', 'alert alert-danger')
        else:
            flash('El usuario no existe.', 'alert alert-danger')


        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    
    return render_template('login.html', **context)
```

I'm not using the username as the primary key, I have a separate id column for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, from context, that `user_query = get_user(username)` is actually a User object and not a query, making a new User and passing it to `login_user` before persisting it mean that its `id` will be be `None`.

The easy fix would be to replace

```
if password == db_password:
    registeredUser = User(username = username,
                          password = password)
    login_user(registeredUser)
```

with

```
if password == user_query.password:
    login_user(user_query)
```

and then to consider renaming `user_query` to `user` so that the code is clearer.

Also, give some thought to not storing user password in the clear. The [Flask Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins) has a chapter that'll walk you through a way to store passwords encrypted.